# Default value on Left

Tags: scala

I make a call to external function and in return have several `Either`. Say I have

```
val a = Right("hey")
val b = Right(2)
val c = Left("oops") .....

for{
 x <- a.right
 y <- b.right
 z <- c.right
} yield(User(x,y,z))
```

But say, if `z` is a Left as above. Then I wish to give it a default String. i.e. by

```
for{
 x <- a.right
 y <- b.right
 z <- c.right.getOrElse(Right("default String")).right
} yield(User(x,y,z))
```

It is dirty. How can I reduce this: `c.right.getOrElse(Right("default String")).right`. Doing `c.right.getOrElse("default")` will not work as a `map` on String returns IndexedSeq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplified syntax can be defined by right-biasing `Either` *implicitly*, as suggested in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/scala-debate/K6wv6KphJK0%5B126-150-false%5D)

```
val user = {
  implicit def rightBiasEither[A, B](e: Either[A, B]): Either.RightProjection[A,B] =
    e.right

  for {
    x <- a
    y <- b
    z <- c getOrElse (Right("default string"))
  } yield User(x, y, z)
}
```

You can choose where to explicitly have right-biasing using a *limiting scope*, as in the example code above, or *wrapping the conversion in a custom object* to import at will, as is customary.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to do this:

```
def rightOrElse[A, B](e1: Either[A, B], e2: => Either[A, B]): Either[A, B] =
  e1.right.flatMap(_ => e2)
```

You'd still need to call `.right` on the result, to make the types match in your for-comprehension.

This is much easier to do with [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s `\/` (disjunction) type (an improved version of `Either`). Not only is it right-biased, avoiding the need to work through a `right` projection, but it has a richer API including an `orElse` method.

```
val a = \/.right("hey")
val b = \/.right(2)
val c = \/.left("oops")

for {
  x <- a
  y <- b
  z <- c orElse \/.right("default String")
} yield User(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Any other prettier way using the scala api?

Comment: If you will be working with Either-type constructs a lot, and particularly if you are intermixing them with Options and other Monadic types, you may well find it worth your while to bite the bullet and dive into Scalaz. Its disjunction type is a proper right-biased Monad and can interact better with other Monads via Monad Transformers such as EitherT.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `scala.util.Try`. In short, `Try` is like an `Either` that would both be right biased and force the left type to `Throwable`. If your left type can easily be mapped to instances of `Throwable` then this is a good candidate.

Your first example would then translate to:

```
val a = Try("hey")
val b = Try(2)
val c = Try(sys.error("oops"))

for{
 x <- a
 y <- b
 z <- c
} yield(User(x,y,z))
```

To provide a default value, just use `orElse`:

```
val a = Try("hey")
val b = Try(2)
val c = Try(sys.error("oops"))

for{
 x <- a
 y <- b
 z <- c.orElse(Try("default String"))
} yield(User(x,y,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to consider that you can skip the *for-comprehension* for the last variable:

```
val z = c.fold(Function.const("default string"), identity)
```

or

```
val z = c.right.getOrElse("default string")
```

and then:

```
for{
 x <- a.right
 y <- b.right
} yield(User(x,y,z))
```