# Scala.Either orElse method

Tags: scala, either

What is idiomatic way to work with `Either`'s in Scala? For example when using `Option` I can use `orElse` method to get next optional value if current is `None`. But how to work with `Either` in same way? I didn't find method like `orElse`  to chain Either's (and I understand that it's not good idea to have such method because we lost the `Left` value)

**Edit:** In fact I have a sequence of `if-elseif-elseif-else` expressions each returning `Right` or `Left`. And I want to refactor my code so it become "more functional". So I can replace it with `firstOption orElse secondOption orElse...` if it were `Option`, but how to use here `Either`?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by using a "more functional" construct than an if-else chain?  Is this just an exercise to see what it would be like, or do you have some goal?  (E.g. less boilerplate, less repetition, easier to catch mistakes, etc.?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well there has been a very long [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/K6wv6KphJK0%5B1-25-false%5D) on this. Currently as you said `Either` is unbiased (i.e. Left and Right are treated as same). Hence one does not know what to do if `orElse` is called? Making it Right biased would had solved the problem (As [Tony Morris](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/K6wv6KphJK0%5B1-25-false%5D) puts it, it was a mistake)

So some hacks are: Using LeftProjection or RightProjection. [Right Projection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either$$RightProjection.html&ei=1nkUUpmgBYWSrgfC2oD4DA&usg=AFQjCNEpmqyezTbUBrnRejoyx9Q-7vWKjg&sig2=8QmVqqWoT8UMJdJ7mvbRfw&bvm=bv.50952593,d.bmk) has utility functions map, flatMap, filter etc)

```
val a:Either[String, Int]
val b:Either[String, Int]

for{
x <- a.right //returns a RightProjection of a
y <- b.right
} yield (a,b)
```

Or `a.right.getOrElse(b.right)`. One more solution would be as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330262/default-value-on-left):

```
object Implicits {
    implicit def rightBiasEither[A, B](e: Either[A, B]): Either.RightProjection[A, B] = e.right
  }

import Implicits._
a.getOrElse(b).getOrElse(c)
```

This way you can keep using it as monad.

---

*Update*:

Post Scala 2.12, `Either` is right-biased, which means that `Right` is assumed to be the default case to  operate on. If it is `Left`, operations like `map` and `flatMap` return the `Left` value unchanged:

```
 def doubled(i: Int) = i * 2
 Right(42).map(doubled) // Right(84)
 Left(42).map(doubled)  // Left(42)
```

You can read more on the [Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) API.

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`Either#orElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Either.html#orElse[A1%3E:A,B1%3E:B](or:=%3Escala.util.Either[A1,B1]):scala.util.Either[A1,B1]) has been made available, (after `Either` being made right-biased in `Scala 2.12`):

```
Right(1) orElse Left(2) // Right(1)
Left(1) orElse Left(2)  // Left(2)
Left(1) orElse Left(2) orElse Right(3) // Right(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

the most closest :

```
Left(1).left.flatMap(_=>Left(2)).left.flatMap(_=>Left(3))
res22: Either[Int, Nothing] = Left(3)

Right(1).left.flatMap(_=>Left(2)).left.flatMap(_=>Left(3))
res23: Either[Int, Int] = Right(1)
```

Use `Try` if you are dealing with `Throwable`:

```
either1.toTry orElse either2.toTry
```

Yes , in my opinion , the lack of `orElse` is inconsistency since `Either` now at 2.12 is right-biased and there's `getOrElse` method.

Comment: Now that `Either` is right-biased, I think a pull request adding `orElse` would be accepted. At least, I can't see why it wouldn't.